# What is current viewport in R grid graphics?

Tags: r, graphics

Here is the code:

```
grid.newpage()
pushViewport(plotViewport(c(5, 4, 2, 2)))
pushViewport(dataViewport(pressure$temperature, pressure$pressure, name="plotRegion"))
data(pressure)
grid.points(pressure$temperature, pressure$pressure, name='datapoints')
grid.ls(viewports=T)
# ROOT
#   GRID.VP.32
#     plotRegion
#       datapoints
current.viewport()
# viewport[plotRegion]
```

I am a little confused, why is the current viewport not 'dotapoints'?

According to the documentation:

> There is only ever one current viewport, which is the current
>        position within the viewport tree.  All drawing and viewport
>        operations are relative to the current viewport.  **When a viewport**
>        **is pushed it becomes the current viewport.**  When a viewport is
>        popped, the parent viewport becomes the current viewport.  Use
>        ‘upViewport’ to navigate to the parent of the current viewport,
>        without removing the current viewport from the viewport tree.  Use
>        ‘downViewport’ to navigate to a viewport further down the viewport
>        tree and ‘seekViewport’ to navigate to a viewport anywhere else in
>        the tree.

Comment: it's a grob, not a viewport. Try `grid.ls(viewports=T, grobs=F)`

Comment: Nice. Why is there a GRID.VP.32 that has never been created?

Comment: Wait a minute, both the plotViewport and dataViewport function produce viewport objects, according to the documentation.

Comment: qed answered your previous question, qed.

Comment: :), but why does `pushViewport(plotViewport(...))` results in a viewport, while `pushViewport(dataViewport(...))` does not?

Comment: you gave a name to dataViewport ("plotRegion"), but none to plotViewport, so grid made one up ("GRID.VP.32")